# Geode/GemFire/PCF/SCDF error - user not authorized for DATA:WRITE / DATA:READ permission

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

We are using Spring Cloud Data Flow to build stream pipe. The spring-cloud-dataflow-server version is 2.8.3.

The out of box sink module **gemfire** is provided by official site: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.8.3/reference/htmlsingle/#applications

Here is the source code of this module: https://github.com/spring-attic/gemfire/tree/v2.1.4.RELEASE

Recently the server end enabled the Gemfire security Authorization feature. On client end we set username/password in SCDF stream definition. But when the data sink to Gemfire, we got user not authorized for DATA:WRITE / DATA:READ error. I attached the details at the end.

The problem is, gemfire server end already granted client's user DATA READ/WRITE permission, and this gemfire sink module can write data into database. But meanwhile we are keep getting this error.

According to the Spring Project Version Compatibility Matrix:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/wiki/Spring-Boot-for-Apache-Geode-and-VMware-Tanzu-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix
We tried all different Apache Geode version, but all of them got the same error.

Is there any way to handle this issue?

```
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [messageHandler]; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: remote server on 93aed963-4624-4e01-6227-954e(23:loner):47226:c35a0e8b: org.apache.geode.security.NotAuthorizedException: user not authorized for DATA:WRITE:WriteTest; nested exception is org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerOperationException: remote server on 93aed963-4624-4e01-6227-954e(23:loner):47226:c35a0e8b: org.apache.geode.security.NotAuthorizedException: user not authorized for DATA:WRITE:WriteTest, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=PDX[4548420,__GEMFIRE_JSON]{read_datetime=2022-03-15T00:52:40:722Z}, headers={id=8ef8d368-87a7-addc-1074-06bb58043933, timestamp=1647305561161}]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.14.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.14.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.14.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.14.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:369) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$400(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:74) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:431) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:402) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1316) [spring-kafka-2.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.12.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1299) [spring-kafka-2.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.12.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1259) [spring-kafka-2.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.12.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1240) [spring-kafka-2.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.12.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1155) [spring-kafka-2.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.12.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:965) [spring-kafka-2.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.12.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:772) [spring-kafka-2.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.12.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:705) [spring-kafka-2.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.12.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_242]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_242]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [messageHandler]; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: remote server on 93aed963-4624-4e01-6227-954e(23:loner):47226:c35a0e8b: org.apache.geode.security.NotAuthorizedException: user not authorized for DATA:WRITE:WriteTest; nested exception is org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerOperationException: remote server on 93aed963-4624-4e01-6227-954e(23:loner):47226:c35a0e8b: org.apache.geode.security.NotAuthorizedException: user not authorized for DATA:WRITE:WriteTest
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:189) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:186) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.gemfire.sink.GemfireSinkHandler.handle(GemfireSinkHandler.java:65) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-gemfire-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor121.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.14.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.14.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:624) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:491) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:362) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ... 29 common frames omitted
2022-03-14T20:52:41.232-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: remote server on 93aed963-4624-4e01-6227-954e(23:loner):47226:c35a0e8b: org.apache.geode.security.NotAuthorizedException: user not authorized for DATA:WRITE:WriteTest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, using ***Spring Boot for Apache Geode*** [equally for GemFire] (SBDG), particularly when running in a Pivotal CloudFoundry (PCF) environment connecting your Spring [Boot] app, or in your case, *Spring Cloud Data Flow* (SCDF) app, to a Pivotal Cloud Cache (PCC) service instance (i.e. GemFire in PCF), then SBDG will automatically connect, authenticate and authorize your application once your Spring [Boot] app has been pushed up to PCF.

> NOTE: Pivotal CloudFoundry (PCF) is now known as VMware Tanzu Appliation Service (TAS) and Pivotal Cloud Cache (PCC) is now known as VMware Tanzu GemFire for VMS.

Of course, this assumes that the PCF/PCC environment, and specifically, the VCAP environment variables, were setup and configured properly when the PCC service instance was provisioned.

If you are not using ***Spring Boot for Apache Geode***, then there is no "automatic" inspection of the PCF/PCC environment (VCAP env vars) and therefore, you become responsible for handling connections, auth, etc.

SBDG was specifically designed to handle these concerns across environments and provides *auto-configuration* to handle connections, auth and other concerns when a Spring Boot app is pushed up to PCF connected to PCC.

More details can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#cloudfoundry).

Additionally, the [Getting Started Sample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/guides/getting-started.html) walks a user through building a Spring Boot app using Apache Geode in a local context, then switching to a non-managed client/server topology locally, and finally pushing and running the app in a managed context like PCF, connecting (and authenticating) with PCC.

All of this **requires** SBDG though.

I am not certain that SCDF uses SBDG under the hood.  It may simply only use ***Spring Data for Apache Geode*** (SDG), in which case, you may need to swap out the SDG dependency for SBDG.

There is most likely other work involved in this process as well since it is unclear to me what specific GemFire/Geode objects (e.g. a cache instance) SCDF creates on your behalf when using SCDF (sources/sinks) that may conflict with the *auto-configuration* provided in and by SBDG.

For instance, if SCDF creates a cache instance (i.e. `ClientCache`) for you, then it will override the SBDG *auto-configuration* that automatically creates a `ClientCache` instance][3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-clientcache-applications), by default. If this is the case, then once again, you become responsible for security (auth) since security must be configured before an GemFire/Geode cache instance (e.g. `ClientCache`) is created.

> NOTE: This is a GemFire/Geode requirement, not a Spring requirement.

Therefore, SBDG's *auto-configuration* arrangement is very deliberate in its precedence and ordering when being applied.  If the SBDG *auto-configuration* is explicitly overridden either by you, or implicitly by another framework (e.g. SCDF), then you become responsible for knowing the expectations (internals) of GemFire/Geode configuration.

On the other hand, if you are certain SBDG is in the application classpath and being used properly, then perhaps this problem stems from the app using the wrong assigned user.

If your environment is rather complex, declaring multiple users with different sets of assigned permissions, then maybe your app needs to be run with a different user assignment, in which case, you should review this particular [section of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#cloudfoundry-cloudcache-security-auth-runtime-user-configuration).

As always you should make sure you Spring [Boot | CDF] application runs correctly in a local, non-managed environment with the similar setup and configuration before running remotely in a managed environment like PCF.

The [goals](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#introduction-goals) of SBDG have always been clear and SBDG is tested and proven to this effect.

Please share as many specifics (code, configuration, etc) as you can here in order for us to be able to triage this problem correctly.

Comment: Here is the source code of that sink app:

https://github.com/spring-attic/gemfire/tree/v2.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: Here is our SCDF stream definition: 

acceptance_streamcreate=stream create SCDF_ufchWarnAndWrite --definition ":SCDF_validUFCH > PskUtUfchWarningCheck  --outputType=application/json | PskGemfireKafka  --json=true --regionName=WriteTest --keyExpression=payload.getField('id')  --hostAddresses=host1:10334,host2:10334 --connectType=locator --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.maxAttempts=1"
acceptance_streamname=SCDF_ufchWarnAndWrite
acceptance_streamdeploy=stream deploy SCDF_ufchWarnAndWrite --propertiesFile SCDF_acceptance_ufchWarnAndWrite.properties

Comment: Here is the corresponding properties file:

deployer.PskGemfireKafka.count=3
deployer.PskUtUfchWarningCheck.cloudfoundry.health-check=process
app.PskUtUfchWarningCheck.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.minPartitionCount=60
app.PskUtUfchWarningCheck.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency=20
app.PskGemfireKafka.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.minPartitionCount=60
app.PskGemfireKafka.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency=20
app.PskUtUfchWarningCheck.spring.kafka.consumer.valueDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

Comment: Continue: app.PskGemfireKafka.spring.kafka.consumer.valueDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
app.PskUtUfchWarningCheck.spring.kafka.consumer.groupId=SCDF_ufchWarnAndWrite_PskUtUfchWarningCheck
app.PskGemfireKafka.spring.kafka.consumer.groupId=SCDF_ufchWarnAndWrite_PskGemfireKafka
deployer.*.cloudfoundry.services=kafka_shared-credhub-sb
deployer.PskGemfireKafka.cloudfoundry.services=gemfire_shared-credhub-sb,kafka_shared-credhub-sb

Comment: Continue:
app.PskGemfireKafka.gemfire.security.ssl.sslKeystorePassword=${vcap.services.gemfire_shared-credhub-sb.credentials.shared-gemfire-ssl-keystore-password}
app.PskGemfireKafka.gemfire.security.ssl.sslTruststorePassword=${vcap.services.gemfire_shared-credhub-sb.credentials.shared-gemfire-ssl-keystore-password}
app.PskGemfireKafka.gemfire.security.ssl.truststoreUri=classpath:gemfire.keystore.jks
app.PskGemfireKafka.gemfire.security.ssl.keystoreUri=classpath:gemfire.keystore.jks

Comment: Continue: app.PskGemfireKafka.gemfire.security.username=${vcap.services.gemfire_shared-credhub-sb.credentials.security-username}
app.PskGemfireKafka.gemfire.security.password=${vcap.services.gemfire_shared-credhub-sb.credentials.security-password}
app.PskUtUfchWarningCheck.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionKeyExpression=headers['fileName_header']
app.PskUtUfchWarningCheck.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionCount=60

Comment: I'm not sure if SBDG's auto-configuration involved when the app connects to the server and doing authorization. In the source code, it is not explicitly configure Spring Boot version, but I checked the parent pom.xml and the parent of parent pom.xml of this app. It is provide spring boot configuration:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/app-starters-build/2.1.3.RELEASE/app-starters-build-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-build/2.1.11.RELEASE/spring-cloud-build-2.1.11.RELEASE.pom

Comment: The GemfireSecurityProperties.java in this gemfire sink app uses Spring Boot annotation @ConfigurationProperties to set the username/password. If SBDG's auto-configuration involved, this annotation could be a possibility:

https://github.com/spring-attic/gemfire/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-stream-common-gemfire/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/gemfire/config/GemfireSecurityProperties.java

Comment: This Spring Cloud Stream app is using SDG, not SBDG. See here: https://github.com/spring-attic/gemfire/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/gemfire-app-dependencies/pom.xml#L45-L55, The dependency should rather be: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#maven-gradle.

Comment: Additionally, the Spring Boot annotated `@ConfigurationProperties` class (`GemfireSecurityProperties`) you referenced above has very little to do with anything from SDG or SBDG's perspective, and actually, is most likely the cause of your auth problems in this case. The fact that the Spring Cloud Stream app implements the GemFire/Geode `AuthInitialize` interface directly (https://github.com/spring-attic/gemfire/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-stream-common-gemfire/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/gemfire/config/GemfireSecurityProperties.java#L62) implies...

Comment: ... that it foolishly does not use the built-in support offered by SDG and SBDG. Therefore, the app makes GemFire/Geode security configuration its responsibility!

Comment: Technically, when pushing and running Spring apps of any kind up to PCF and using PCC, you should not be specifying any username and password directly in Spring Boot `application.properties`, `spring.properties` or otherwise.  The auth credentials come from the PCF VCAP environment variables that get configured when you provisioned the PCC service instance in which your app will connect.

Comment: In conclusion, if you are encountering GemFire/Geode permission errors or any other type of auth errors, then clearly the security configuration of the SCDF app when running in PCF connected to a PCC service instance is not correct.  Ironically, this is exactly what SBDG with the SDG as the foundation was meant to handle.  If teams and apps are going to forgo the Security configuration offered in and by SDG and the Security auto-configuration offered by SBDG, then the team/app is responsible for that themselves.

Comment: I know this is not your app, but I would reach out to the Spring Cloud Stream app(s) team, since this is where the problem and responsibility lies.